# How do I find a match for 24 digit alphanumeric query for .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,24})$ poem.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: What isn't working? Your regex matches any alnum string from 1 to 24 characters.

Comment: Actually, it is working. And now another rewrite rule is not working. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?membername=$1 [L] doesn't work. It has worked. But not since I added this newer rule.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the new information.

Comment: Also please be specific: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: What do you want when you have `abcd1234` ?  `profile.php?member=$1` or `poem.php?id=$1`

Answer (score 0):

(Someone edited this and it popped up in the queue; may as well give it an answer.)

The `[L]` flag indicates that this is the last rule, and that no more should be processed. His next rule wasn't being processed as a result.

Correct setup should be:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,24})$ poem.php?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?membername=$1 [L]
```